# What is public static function create() in plugins for?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

Sometimes I encounter a public static function `create()` in plugin classes, for the example in the code show in [Tutorial on Using Drupal 8 Plugin Derivatives Effectively](https://www.sitepoint.com/tutorial-on-using-drupal-8-plugin-derivatives-effectively/).

```php
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, $base_plugin_id) {
  return new static(
    $container->get('entity.manager')->getStorage('node')
  );
}
```

Could you clarify me what the purpose of that function is, for example what it should do and where it's used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

create() is a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) for dependency injection.

Plugins which implement `ContainerFactoryPluginInterface` are instantiated by `create()` of the plugin class:

*ContainerFactory::createInstance*

```
public function createInstance($plugin_id, array $configuration = []) {
  ...
  // If the plugin provides a factory method, pass the container to it.
  if (is_subclass_of($plugin_class, 'Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface')) {
    return $plugin_class::create(\Drupal::getContainer(), $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
  }

  // Otherwise, create the plugin directly.
  return new $plugin_class($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's the static method Drupal core uses to create the plugin. (See, for example, the documentation for [`SystemMenuBlock::create()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21Plugin%21Block%21SystemMenuBlock.php/function/SystemMenuBlock%3A%3Acreate/8.6.x).)

Drupal core doesn't instantiate a plugin with `new PluginClass()`, but `PluginClass::create()`. This allows the class implementing the plugin to return an instance previously created.
The other *pro* is that the signature of the plugin constructors can vary without giving problems to Drupal, which just requires the `create()` method of a class of plugins to always have  the same signature.

It is the same pattern used for Drupal services.