# What is the logic of create method in ContainerInterface class & its argument when being used and how its related to argument of the construct method?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_changes\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
/**
 * Block to determine the weather
 * @Block(
 *   id = "weather_block",
 *   admin_label = "Weather Block",
 *   category = @Translation("Hello World"),
 * )
 */
class CustomWeatherBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface
{

    /**
     * The HTTP client to fetch the feed data with.
     *
     * @var \GuzzleHttp\Client
     */
      protected $httpClient;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, Client $http_client) {
       $this->httpClient = $http_client;
    }

    public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition){
       return new static(
         $configuration,
         $plugin_id,
         $plugin_definition, 
         $container->get('http_client')
       );
    }
```

What does `return new static()` mean inside `CustomWeatherBlock` class and why do I need to pass all the arguments
 - $configuration
 - $plugin_id
 - $plugin_definition
 as in the construct and how is construct and create related to each other?
because when I tried to pass just $container->get('http_client') inside

```
return new static(
  $container->get('http_client')
);
```

whereas when I pass

```
return new static(
  $configuration,
  $plugin_id,
  $plugin_definition,
  $container->get('http_client')
);
```

It does not give any error.
I need to understand why is it so ?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264767/what-is-public-static-function-create-in-plugins-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create()` is a static method called on this class, before it is instantiated (static methods don't require instantiation of the class). The `create()` method returns the arguments that are passed to `__construct()`.

> Whereas when I pass:
>
> ```
> return new static(
>   $configuration,
>   $plugin_id,
>   $plugin_definition,
>   $container->get('http_client')
> );
> ```
>
> It does not give any error. I need to understand why is it so?

Plugins that implement the `ContainerAwareInterface` pass the additional arguments of `$configuration`, `$plugin_id` and `$plugin_definition` to the create() function. These must be returned, as the `__construct()` argument will require these values in plugins.

Comment: what is the significance of ContainerAwareInterface here since I see only setContainer() is defined in the Interface ?  how is that connected,sorry if its silly question ?

Comment: Plugins that do not implement it will not even call create().

Comment: I was under impression to call create you need to implement ContainerFactoryPluginInterfaceand to get the container you need to implement ContainerAwareInterface as it has method setContainer() ?
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Plugin%21ContainerFactoryPluginInterface.php/interface/ContainerFactoryPluginInterface/8.2.x 

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21dependency-injection%21ContainerAwareInterface.php/interface/ContainerAwareInterface/8.2.x